# making more than one activity in a tab

Tags: android, tabs

I really want to move from an activity within a tab view to another activity within the same tab.

```
public void onClick (View view) {
    // This creates an intent to call the 'Called' activity             
    i1 = new Intent(this.getBaseContext(),Called.class);

    // calls the method to replace View.    
    replaceContentView("Called", i1);
}
```

Comment: You  should consider using Fragments for this issue.

Comment: Use fragments if you are using android 3.0 or higher, see this link... [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
TabSpec spec=...//our tabSpec
Intent intent = new Intent(this.getBaseContext(), Called.class);
spec.setContent(videosIntent);
```